# Extract values from raster based on weighted average area using polygon grid

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, area, zonal-statistics

EDIT: I am using Armap 10 sp 5
I have found similar questions but they were either unanswered or somewhat different to what I am asking.

I have a raster with cell values 1-5 and a polygon shape file with regular grid of squares the same size.

All I need as output is a table with the polygon ID and the raster value. I tried to use the zonal tool but in the option it does not have a weighted average based on the area that each raster cell occupies in the polygon grid cell. For example in a grid cell I might have two raster cells, one of value 2 that occupies 30% of the area and one value 5 that occupies 70%. My result would be 2*.3+5*.7=4.1 instead of 3.5 that I get with zonal tools.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?  Please edit that detail into your question and tags.

Comment: You're on the right track: Resample the raster to a finer cellsize (so that each polygon contains many cells) and try again.

Comment: @whuber well that might be one solution, my grid is 10km, so what would be a fine enough cellsize?

Comment: It depends on the accuracy you need.  In my experience, resampling so that each polygon contains at least 100 cells is often good enough.

Comment: @whuber ok I am trying your approach, however the zonal statistics doesn't go through and I get a few error messages. error in executing grid expression zonal statistics program failed, and also "the fields collection contained multiple oid fields"